# TYPO3 Constant Editor is not working with Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.7.x

In TYPO3 8.7.8 and 7.6.23 (I tested this two versions) you cannot enable or disable boolean fields in Internet Explorer (tested with Version 11) or Microsoft Edge: the click is not "recognized" on the checkbox. It is no problem with Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm this. TYPO3 8.7.8.
Looks like a bug

Comment: Thank you I opend a bug in forge: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82998?next_issue_id=82995